# Using array method map to aggregate an array of dictionaries with an array

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `array` representing (for example) the days of the week:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wed", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sat", "Sunday"]
```

I have a `array of dictionaries` of the SAME size of my first array, each `Dictionary` contains only one `key/value`:

```
[["temp": 11], ["temp": 12], ["temp": 13], ["temp": 14], ["temp": 15], ["temp": 16], ["temp": 17]]
```

Each temperature correspond to the day of the same index in the first array.

Is there a way, using the array method `map(transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T)`, to transform my array of dictionaries into the following dictionary:

```
 ["Monday": 11, "Tuesday": 12, "Wed": 13, "Thursday": 14, "Friday": 15, "Sat": 16, "Sunday": 17]
```

Comment: You do not have Dictionary anywhere. Second data model is also an Array. Its an array of strings `"temp: 11"`. Dictionaries cannot have same keys. Check your model and question please.

Comment: Well again check, as I said, Dictionary must have unique keys. Try to put your model in Swift playground and you must get error.

Comment: ok so now, second one is array of dictionaries. Is that what you want? Why can you simply have an array of just numbers like 11, 12, 13 and then merge your day array and number array to make one dictionary? Not sure what you want to achieve thought. Throw some more light please!

Comment: Yes, the array of dictionary I get it from core data using a fetchRequest with a `resultType = .DictionaryResultType`. And the array of days, it's the predicate for the fetchRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can return only `Array` from `map` and not `Dictionary`. Here is an alternate way of doing this:

```
var test1 = [["temp": 11], ["temp": 12], ["temp": 13], ["temp": 14], ["temp": 15], ["temp": 16], ["temp": 17]]
var myArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wed", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sat", "Sunday"]
var finalArray = [Dictionary<String,Int?>]()

for day in myArray {
    let itemIndex = myArray.indexOf(day)
    let itemDict = test1[itemIndex!]
    let value = itemDict["temp"] as Int?
    let changedDict = [day : value]
    finalArray.append(changedDict)
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about iterating through the array but was wondering if it was possible to do it with map. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You should either iterate over `myArray.enumerated()` or `myArray.indices`. That `.indexOf` there is unnecessary and bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously work for [zip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip):

```
var test1: [[String: Any]] = [["temp": 11], ["temp": 12], ["temp": 13], ["temp": 14], ["temp": 15], ["temp": 16], ["temp": 17]]
var myArray = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wed", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sat", "Sunday"]

let temps = test1.compactMap { $0["temp"] as? Int }

let finalArray: [[String: Int]] = zip(temps, myArray)
    .map { (temp, day) in [day: temp] }
print(finalArray)
```